# Two Python instances, same libraries

Tags: python, linux, libraries

I currently have both Python 2.6 and 2.7 running on my Linux machine.

Now, from Python 2.7, I can't access the libraries that I installed through package manager for Python 2.6.

I tried uninstalling the library and installing it back with Python 2.7 installed as my default runtime. No luck.

How can I share libraries between two Python instances? Is there a more correct way to do this than just copying them?

If useful: my Linux distro is Debian, and my package manager is `apt`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to install the files to an external location and define the environment variable `PYTHONPATH` to point to the directory that contains the modules.

Answer (score 0):

You should have now both a /usr/lib/python2.6 folder and a /usr/lib/python2.7. Try creating links inside the 2.7 folders to the required files or folders inside the 2.6 folder.